# Looping comparing two values in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, correlation

While looping over a partially filled correlation matrix (it has been filtered beforehand), I want to compare the variances for the two variables within the loop and keep the variable with the highest variance in a vector.

This is a capture of the correlation matrix:

[image]

Variances have been calculated in a separate dataframe (var) and the order of the variances coincides with the order of the variables in the correlation matrix.

[image]

The snippet of code that does not work is as follows:

```
vec <- c()

for (i in ncol(mcor)) {
  for (j in nrow(mcor)) {
    if (is.na(mcor[i,j])) {
      j = j+1      
    } else {
      if (var[j,2] > var[i,2]) {
        vec <- c(vec, var[j,2])
      } else {
        vec <- c(vec, var[i,2])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops are not defined correctly. Try

```
for (i in 1:ncol(mcor)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(mcor)) {
...
```